# I would like to display a code snippet in a text area so it can easily be cut and pasted, how?

Tags: php, html

I am generating a bit of code to display a picture as a link (frex `<a href="site.com"><img src="/image.gif"></a>`) I would like to show how it look, but also in a textbox adjacent show the actual code. Is there a function in PHP that will automagically escape HTML code so it can be displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print "<textarea>" . htmlspecialchars($html) . "</textarea>";
```

[**Here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) you can find details about htmlspecialchars from official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)